# Comparing a string[] to a list of objects with stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of:

```
String[] properties = {"prop1","prop2","prop3"};
List<CustomObject> listOfObjects; // contains objects and each object contains a property of `properties` array

class CustomObject{
   String prop1;
   String prop2;
   String prop3;

}
```

I want to check every `properties` value to every `listOfObjects` objects properties and check if the value is empty. I just want to check that none of the objects have empty properties.

I know there's `stream()` but I'm not sure how to use it correctly.

```
listOfObjects.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.get(/*What do i put in here?*/) == "");
```

Update: here's what would basically work without `stream()`

```
    for(String prop: properties) {
        for(CustomObject pdo: listOfObjects) {
            if(pdo.get(prop) == "") {
                System.out.println("Some of the required fields are empty");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really. Just a check whether any of the properties is empty.

Comment: @Oops sorry. Misread

Comment: 1. Why a `List<Object>`, use some custom object. 2. `get` would depend on the type of object . 3 use `equals` to compare strings.

Comment: Sorry, it is a custom object. I will edit.

Comment: You want to check that both array and collection do not have empty values? Right?

Comment: I want to check if the list of custom object has any properties which are in string[] and check if they are empty. @AndreyIlyunin

Comment: There is no simple builtin facility to treat a `String` like an object’s property. This is not Javascript.

Comment: @Holger but there's a .get(String arg0) for the list of custom objects which gets the correct property.

Comment: How are we supposed to know that your `CustomObject` class has a `get(String)` method? That’s not what we call a “property” in Java. A property would imply the presence of `getProp1()`, `getProp2()`, and `getProp3()` methods.

Comment: I guess I should have called them class members not properties.

Comment: what does .get(String prop) return if the property is not found?

Comment: @Brad Sorry, but that's not relevant since the array of strings and class members of customobject match.

Comment: Please share the `CustomObject` class definition. I think that's the most crucial part that you've abstracted from the question && *3. use `equals` to compare strings.*

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of using Streams and anyMatch you can use this operation to check if any of the properties are blank. This is just to answer your question specifically, my suggestion is to take some time and improve this as there is a lot of room.

```
listOfObject.stream()
                .anyMatch(obj -> Arrays.stream(obj)
                        .anyMatch(p -> !(obj.get(p)!= null && !obj.get(p).isEmpty())));
```

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking for, I will test it later and accept if it does work.

Comment: Instead of `.equals("")`, you can use `.isEmpty()`.

Comment: Good point, made me think about the case where the value retrieved by the get method is null. Currently with `.equals()` it would return false and would invalidate the outcome, and with `.isEmpty` it would raise a `NullPointerException`. I will update my answer, considering this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a list of `Predicate`s. Each of the following predicates tests one of the properties for equality against `""`.

```
List<Predicate<CustomObject>> propertiesCheckers = 
        Arrays.asList(pdo -> "".equals(pdo.get("prop1")),
            pdo -> "".equals(pdo.get("prop2")),
            pdo -> "".equals(pdo.get("prop3")));
```

And this stream checks each element against the predicate, returning `true` when the first empty value is found:

```
boolean anyEmpty = listOfObjects.stream()
        .flatMap(ob -> propertiesCheckers.stream().map(pred -> pred.test(ob)))
        .anyMatch(b -> b); //returns true if any "".equals returned true

if(anyEmpty) System.out.println("Some of the required fields are empty");
```

Comment: 1. Though honestly, I am not very sure if I understand the question right. But, does this not miss the relation between the `String [] properties` in the question to the `List<CustomObejct> listOfObjects` somewhere? 2. There is also a typo in your checkers left with `emp`.

Comment: @nullpointer Thanks, fixed typo. Edited to use the added example in the question. So I'm proposing the OP change `String [] properties` to `List<Predicate<CustomObject>>` based on those property names.